# Ideal computer specifications for own staking?

Tags: staking

I'm very new to Cardano and staking and would like to run my own vs delegating:

- what PC specifications would be ideal to run my own pool for ADA staking?

Comment: Why would you want to run your own vs. delegating? This is only advisable if you have millions of ADA or are going to start a stake pool business.

Answer (score 6):

To earn staking rewards, there is no requirement to run your own pool. You can use [Yoroi](https://yoroi-wallet.com/) app for Phone or [Daedalus](https://daedaluswallet.io/) application for Computer. You can delegate to pools in the app and earn rewards. Ensure that you are using a verified application else you will lose your funds to scammers.

If you want to start run a stake pool, please read about the economics of running a stake pool. You will require about 1M ADA to run a profitable stake pool at the moment. If you have less money, you need to find people with this much ADA to delegate to your pool. Currently, there are about 2500 pools, and it's a tough business to get delegators.
The recommended specifications for a topology of a stake pool are 1 - Block Producer Node and 2 Relay Nodes. The configuration [reference](https://github.com/input-output-hk/technical-docs/blob/main/getting-started/stake-pool-operators/hardware-requirements.md) of the computer for this node are:

- 4 GB of RAM (8-12 GB ideal)
- 24 GB of hard disk space (200 GB Ideal)
- a good network connection and about 1 GB of bandwidth per hour
- a public IP4 address